# C++ undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I am running this code on Linux Mint:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Config.h"
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    shared_ptr<Config> config = make_shared<Config>("WorldServer");
    string def = "Nothing there.";
    Logger::Log("Authserver Conn: " + config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabaseInfo", def));

    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        const string host = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.IP", def);
        const string mysqlUser = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.IP", def);
        const string mysqlPassword = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.IP", def);
        const string mysqlDatabase = config->GetConfigValue("LoginDatabase.MySQL.IP", def);

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect(host, mysqlUser, mysqlPassword);
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema(mysqlPassword);

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM accounts");
        while (res->next()) {
            cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
            /* Access column data by alias or column name */
            cout << res->getString("warTag") << endl;
            cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
            /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
            cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to build it I receive the following error:

```
undefined reference to `get_driver_instance`
```

I also have this installed:

```
sudo apt-get install  libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

What can be the cause of this problem and how can I fix it ?

Comment: It seems you need to link the MySQL driver library. How are you building your program?

Comment: I am using cmake how can I link it in it ?

Comment: See the target_link_libraries statement in the cmake documentation.

Comment: I have linked MySQL Library but it still shows the same error.

Comment: "I have linked MySQL Library". Show, don't tell. [Edit] the question and add commands, makefiles, cmakefiles or whatever else you used to link your program. "When I try to build it" contains no useful information.